# Chain of observables with conditions

Tags: angular, rxjs, iif, concatmap

So I have 3 observables: updateCustomUserData$, updateEmail$, updatePassword$.
And profileEditForm.
I need to update profile data if appropriate fields of form was changed;
I think it should look like this:

```
updateCustomUserData$(data) {
  return iif(() => customDataWasChanged(), apiService.updateCustomUserData())
}

// updateEmail$ and updatePassword$ is similar


onSubmit() {
  this.updateCustomUserData$(formData).pipe(
    concatMap(() => this.updateEmail$(newEmail))),
    concatMap(() => this.updatePassword$(newPassword),
  )
  .subscribe(() => doSomething())
}
```

But it is not working. If custom data was not changed and password or email do - updateEmail & updatePassword is not executing.
Is anybody can help?
P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Comment: 1. The `iif` operator isn't returned. 2. The condition in the `iif` is empty.

Comment: 1. I was forget return iif in there, but not in my code. 2. customDataWasChanged() return boolean. This is condition

Answer (score 0):

When onSubmit method is called?
I think you should define ngOnInit instead of onSubmit.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateCustomUserData$(formData).pipe(
      concatMap(() => this.updateEmail$(newEmail))),
      concatMap(() => this.updatePassword$(newPassword),
    )
    .subscribe(() => doSomething())  }
}
```

Comment: onSubmit is called with the Submit button click